# No se quiere insertar los datos en la base de datos MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy haciendo un sitio web de películas y llevo más de 4 horas tratando de buscar el error de por que no quiere entrar esos datos a la base de datos. Estoy usando PHP y MySQL (PHPMyAdmin) y no me dice la razón. Realmente no se si ese error de trata del XAMPP ya que es primera vez que no se quiere añadir

En fin. este es mi código PHP

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "newfowflix";

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
$titulo_original=$_POST['titulo_original'];
$sipnosis=$_POST['sipnosis'];
$generos=$_POST['generos'];
$estreno=$_POST['estreno'];
$duracion=$_POST['duracion'];
$imdb=$_POST['imdb'];
$tmdb=$_POST['tmdb'];
$rating=$_POST['rating'];
$poster=$_POST['poster'];
$miniatura=$_POST['miniatura'];
$publicado=$_POST['publicado'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO peliculas (titulo, titulo original, sipnosis, generos, estreno, duracion, imdb, tmdb, rating, poster, miniatura, publicado) VALUES ('$titulo', '$titulo_original', '$sipnosis', '$generos', '$estreno', '$duracion', '$imdb', '$tmdb', '$rating', '$poster', '$miniatura', '$publicado');";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($sql) {
    echo "Pelicula agregada!";
}

?>
```

Este es el código del formulario HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="anadir-pelicula_conf.php">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" placeholder="Título"></br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo_original" placeholder="Título Original"></br>
<input class="form-control" name="sipnosis" placeholder="Sipnosis"></br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="generos" placeholder=""></br>
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="estreno" placeholder=""></br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="duracion" placeholder=""></br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="imdb" placeholder="" ></br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="tmdb" placeholder="" ></br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="rating" placeholder=""></br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="poster" placeholder=""></br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="miniatura" placeholder=""></br>
<select name="publicado" class="form-control">
    <option value="1" selected>Si</option>
    <option value="0">No</option>
</select></br>
<input type="submit" value="Subir" class="btn btn-info">
</form>
```

El primer código php es el archivo **anadir-pelicula_conf.php** el cual manda el *action*. Si tienen una duda hazmelo saber y edito el post.

Comment: Te sugiero que pintes con echo la SQL que generas y la pegues en phpmyadmin para ver el error, verás que se trata del campo "titulo original" que no puede tener un espacio en el nombre.

Comment: Hola, puedes ponr la estructura de tu bd para checarlo?

Comment: @track3r Muchas gracias! No me habia fijado. En la base de datos lo puse con espacio. Al parecer MySQL no acepta tabla con espacio. Intenté ponerlo con *_* y sime funcionó

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar un chequeo del resultado de `mysqli_query` para saber que esta pasando.
Ademas chequear `$sql` en el if nunca te dara falso, ya que es simplemente un string, en este caso es preferible chequear el resultado de mysqli_query (guardado en `$res`)

```
$res= mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

if ($res) {
    echo "Pelicula agregada!";
}
```